# Powershell find and move files

Tags: powershell

I'm having issues with my code below. It results in a "Warning: failed to copy:   " And it does not state what the error is. My goal is to search for the $ErrorCode within the files and move those files to another directory.

```Powershell
function Errors{

    Param (
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $LogPath,#LogPath
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $ErrorCode,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $NetApp

        )

         if (Test-Path -Path $LogPath)
          {
                try  
                    {

                        Get-ChildItem $LogPath -Recurse| Select-String -pattern $ErrorCode | group path | select name  |  ForEach-Object {
                        Copy-Item $_.fullName -Destination $NetApp\$($_.BaseName,$ErrorCode,$_.Extension) } 
                    }
                catch
                    {
                        Write-Warning "Failed to copy: $($file.Fullname) "
                        continue
                    }    
        }
}
```

Comment: i'm surprised that the `catch` block is running at all since you didn't set `-ErrorAction Stop` on anything in the `try` block. [*grin*] ///// you can get the `catch` to show the error by using `$_` in the `catch` - where it otta hold the error that triggered the `catch`. another option is to use the automatic `$Error` variable. it holds errors in last-in order, so the newest will be `$Error[0]`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, I think my main problem is that the error files come out as an array and so I can't copy them all to another destination

Comment: still, you need to find out what is causing the `catch` block to be run. that SHOULD NOT run unless there is a terminating error ... and you are suppressing the info about what when wrong.